# Grassfire algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Anyone has any idea how to perform grassfire in c++?

I am using OpenCV library

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference to the distance transform? There is a function called [cv::distanceTransform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-distancetransform), maybe that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about the pseudocode in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassfire_Transform) link.

It goes like this:

```
 for each row in image left to right
    for each column in image top to bottom
      if(pixel is in region){
        set pixel to 1 + minimum value of the north east neighbours
      }else{
        set pixel to zero
      }
    }
  }

  for each row right to left
    for each column bottom to top
      if(pixel is in region){
        set pixel to min(value of the pixel,1 + minimum value of the south west neighbours)
      }else{
        set pixel to zero
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a modified version of grassfire that I am currently using for BLOB extraction. It takes a digitized (image that has been modified such that all values are either a 1 or a 0) and returns a vector of bounding boxes with the largest first. The code is rather long but its in a public repo at https://github.com/bstadt/JHU-Robotics-compVis in the src/cvLib.cpp file. Also be aware that bounding box is a class that I wrote myself so you'll need that as well. It has its source in the src folder and a header in the include directory, so be sure to grab both of those.