# grass fire algorithm taking way too long, how to optimize?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, time-complexity, complexity-theory

So I am working with openCV and trying to write a bunch of algorithms "from scratch" so to speak so that I can really understand what the library is doing. I wrote a modified grass fire algorithm to segment BLOBs from an image that I have already digitized. However, the algorithm takes over 2 minutes to run on my very capable laptop (16 gigs ram, quad core i7, etc...). What am I doing here that is making it so complex? Alternately, is there a better algorithm for extracting BLOBs from a digitized image?
THANKS!

Here is the algorithm

```
    std::vector<boundingBox> grassFire(cv::Mat digitalImage){
        std::vector<boundingBox> blobList;
        int minY, minX, maxY, maxX, area, yRadius, xRadius, xCenter, yCenter;
        for(int curRow = 0; curRow<digitalImage.rows; curRow++){
                for(int curCol = 0; curCol<digitalImage.cols; curCol++){
                       //if there is something at that spot in the image
                        if((int)digitalImage.at<unsigned char>(curRow, curCol)){
                                minY = curRow;
                                maxY = curRow;
                                minX = curCol;
                                maxX = curCol;
                                area = 0;
                                yRadius = 0;
                                xRadius = 0;
                                for(int fireRow=curRow; fireRow<digitalImage.rows; fireRow++){
                                        //is in keeps track of the row and started keeps track of the col
                                        //is in will break if no pixel in the row is part of the blob
                                        //started will break the inner loop if a nonpixel is reached AFTER a pixel is reached
                                        bool isIn = false;
                                        bool started = false;
                                        for(int fireCol = curCol; fireCol<digitalImage.cols; fireCol++){
                                                //make sure that the pixel is still in
                                                if((int)digitalImage.at<unsigned char>(fireRow, fireCol)){
                                                        //signal that an in pixel has been found
                                                        started = true;
                                                        //signal that the row is still in
                                                        isIn = true;
                                                        //add to the area
                                                        area++;
                                                        //reset the extrema variables
                                                        if(fireCol > maxX){maxX = fireCol;}
                                                        if(fireCol < minX){minX = fireCol;}
                                                        if(fireRow > maxY){maxY = fireRow;}
                                                        //no need to check min y since it is set already by the loop trigger

                                                        //set the checked pixel values to 0 to avoid double counting
                                                        digitalImage.at<unsigned char>(fireRow, fireCol) = 0;
                                                }
                                                //break if the next pixel is not in and youve already seen an in pixel
                                                //do nothing otherwise
                                                else{if(started){break;}}
                                                //if the entire blob has been detected
                                                if(!isIn){break;}
                                        }
                                }
                        }else{}//just continue the loop if the current pixel is not in 
                        //calculate all blob specific values for the blob at hand
                        xRadius =(int)((double)(maxX - minX)/2.);
                        yRadius =(int)((double)(maxY - minY)/2.);
                        xCenter = maxX - xRadius;
                        yCenter = maxY - yRadius;
                        //add the blob to the vector in the appropriate position (largest area first)
                        int pos = 0;
                        for(auto elem : blobList){
                                if(elem.getArea() > area){
                                        pos++;
                                }
                                else{break;}
                        }
                        blobList.insert(blobList.begin() + pos, boundingBox(area, xRadius, yRadius, xCenter, yCenter));
                }
        }

        return blobList;
}
```

Comment: Have you run a profiler on your code ?

Comment: @Borgleader I am unfamilliar with said algorithm so I can not tell you for sure.... however a quick google search leads me to believe that this is different than the staircase algorithm. As I mentioned in the top description, I can best describe it as a modified grass fire algorithm.

Comment: You say `just continue the loop if the current pixel is not in` but you don't continue the loop there, and fall thru to the code that adds another element to `blobList` (which code will access past the end of the lit of no element satisfies the condition in that for loop).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have not since I did not know that such things existed. After a quick google search I think that this is a great tool that I really need to learn as I get into working with more complex algorithms (this is the first time I have ever had a time complexity issue that wasn't rather obvious just through code review). Do you have a specific c++ profiler in mind (ubuntu friendly por favor) that you would recommend?

Comment: No sane programmer have desire to read such a mess. You might want to learn about [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) and how it corellates to number of defects in programs. Start splitting your code into functions and everything will go much better.

Comment: With gcc compiler, `gprof` is a classical profiler.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm you are the closest thing to a superhero that I have run into today. That was exactly the problem! please post it as a solution to I can confirm it!

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the recommendation

Comment: @Drop is it really that bad :( I figured that my commenting made what was going on rather clear, but I suppose it could use some modularity. I will rework it so that there are separate calls to things like inserting the element and the actual search loops once an actual blob has been found. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: you may also find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214925/grassfire-algorithm-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say `just continue the loop if the current pixel is not in but you don't continue the loop there, and fall thru to the code that adds another element to blobList (which code will access past the end of the lit of no element satisfies the condition in that for loop).

And using this

```
for(const auto &elem : blobList)
```

would avoid making copies of all those boundingBoxes.